# Programmatically apply Knockout bindings to specific tags within a text block

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a block of html markup that I'd like to databind to a div using [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/). This is simple enough with the knockout `html` binding.

What I'd like to do is conditionally bind child elements within that html markup, based on their class. These elements can appear anywhere within the html markup, as they are inline elements (like `span`, `a` tags, etc).

The purpose of this is to databind click events to specific words or phrases within this text block, so that I can call a function (in this case, a modal with a definition of the target word or phrase).

Does anyone know how to do this? From what I can see, I have two main avenues to explore:

1. Use jQuery to grab the elements by class, and somehow databind to then after the fact. I don't know if this will work for various
   reasons - not having the DOM ready, not being able to databind in
   that method, etc.
2. Use knockout's [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), and add an `afterRender` template callback that parses the text block for the elements and databinds
   them accordingly.
3. A combination of the two above. (Yeah, I know, that's three avenues.)

Has anyone done anything like this before? I'd like to get your advice and feedback, if possible. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since the bindings need to exist when `ko.applyBindings()` is called.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 - I can think of ways to do it with custom bindings but one issue would be the possibility of duplicate appyBindings if the html contents was updated. Do you plan on updating the contents or is it a one time display?

Comment: @madcapnmckay It's a one-time binding; the contents shouldn't be updated after they're displayed. I hadn't considered a custom binding - how would you solve this using that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend this approach unless you are sure that the html you are binding to is safe. The html binding looks like this.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['html'] = {
    'init': function() {
        // Prevent binding on the dynamically-injected HTML 
        // (as developers are unlikely to expect that, and it 
        // has security implications)
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.utils.setHtml(element, value);
    }
};
```

Looking at this you could write a html2 binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers['html2'] = {
    'init': function() {
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': false };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.utils.setHtml(element, value);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/LDtuF/1/

Be careful with this, you want to make sure the html cannot be used for insecure purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We're receiving the HTML from a secure source - a CMS that should sanitize everything before it's sent out. I'll look into securing this a little more, though.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 - Cool, that should be fine. If this answers you question please accept it as the answer.

Comment: This may work, but I'm wondering about the implications of this - if we ever decide to update the methods, we'd have to change the HTML everywhere in the CMS, which might not be ideal. Whereas, if I can conditionally bind based on a class, there's an extra level of abstraction....

Comment: I did some testing; it looks as though `controlsDescendantBindings` is set to false by default. However, it is the key for getting the descendant bindings to work correctly. I was able to modify the 'update' function to parse the DOM elements using jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked brilliantly. I was able to modify the update function you specified, using jQuery to dynamically add data-bind tags to elements with a specific class.