# jQuery: setting an element attribute to .text()

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a span tag that looks like the following:

```
<span class="myClass">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

I would like to add an attribute to it that references the innerText value (for a javascript function call), and I would like it to look like this:

```
<span class="myClass" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { myFunction('Lorem ipsum') }">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

I want to be able to dynamically parse a paragraph of text that contains spans of span myClass, and add the attribute programmatically. As such, if my innerText was "Sed", the argument to myFunction would be "Sed".

I tried the following to produce this:

```
jquery(container).find('.myClass').attr('data-bind', 'click: function(data, event) { myFunction(' + $(this).text() + ')}');
```

It didn't work. (The function argument was empty. Trying `.html()` outputs "null".)

Does anyone know how to accomplish something like this in jQuery? I believe that my issue is the `$(this)` keyword, as it's not pointing to the object in question. I'm not sure if there's another keyword that I can use...

Thank you!

Edit: Whoops, I attempted to obfuscate my code a little, and forgot to do it for the last line. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: `data-` attributes are supposed to contain static data, not dynamic functions. Furthermore, why would you want to add code to reference the innerText value, instead of just... referencing the innerText value?

Comment: What does the nonGlossaryKeyword class point to?

Comment: @Larry - see edit. I'm working on a company program and thought it wise to genericize my code, but I forgot to do so for the last line.

Comment: @Blazemonger - I'm using knockout.js for databinding; as far as it's concerned, the click binding is static. However, if there's a better way to reference the innerText without using this method, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to do with the text. I'm not familiar with knockout, but mixing it with jQuery is probably unnecessary. In any case I can think of, it's better to create a generic `$('.myClass').on('click',function() {...});` event handler which will retrieve `$(this).text()` and do something with it on demand.

Comment: @Blazemonger Unfortunately, nope. I'm working with a large framework that we've built in Knockout, and it works pretty well; this is the only time that I've had to do something like this (and it's for a custom binding context: see my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10916698/677526) and it has to happen this way because we're dealing with model data sent from a server.

Comment: I've added the knockout tag to your question, since clearly it should be directed at that community instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `$(this)` isn't your element.

try:

```
jquery(container).find('.nonGlossaryKeyword').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('data-bind', 'click: function(data, event) { showNonGlossaryModal(' + $(this).text() + ')}');
});
```

in this case, $(this) iterates over all the .nonGlassorayKeyword elements, like a for loop.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! I'll need to brush up on my jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
jQuery(".myClass") // or $(".myClass")
```

instead of

```
jquery(container).find('.nonGlossaryKeyword')
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer his question, and also, container may very well be a valid jquery element.

Comment: @seth flowers I mean the latter - sorry for the confusion, but it's part of a larger code snippet. (I'm trying to parse a string and had to add it to a div container for jQuery parsing purposes, hence the container.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the keyword 'this' at this time refers to container. I think you can do:

```
var spans = jQuery(container).find('span');  //all spans
jQuery.each(spans,function(i,ele){
     var text = jQuery(ele).text();
     jQuery(ele).attr('data-bind','click: function(data, event) { myFunction("'+text+'")}');
});
```